# Eliminating pixels of a Merged image

Tags: qgis, merge

I need to change the value of pixels that where created in an image as a result of merging 2 rasters, this new pixels have a value of 0. The problem is, that there are pixels with 0 in the original rasters that I need to keep, so I can't just reclasify ...
[image: Green triangles are the original rasters, the second image shows the merged image, with the 2 newly created rectangles with 0]

Answer (score 2):

QGIS uses [GDAL_Merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) to merge the rasters. You can specify the nodata value using `-n <value>`, this should also initialize the rasters with the specified value where there is no overlap.

If this doesn't work then create a box (shapefile) the size of the the image and use [GDAL_Rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) (-b ) to create an empty raster to cover the blank areas then merge the rasters with the background first.